# /video/nid returns a 404 error

Tags: 6, hooks

I am trying to create a module in Drupal 6.22, using the following code.

```php
function example_video_perm() {
  return array("video access");
}

function example_video_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['video/%nid'] = array(
    'title' => '',
    'page callback' => 'video_load',
    'access arguments' => array('video access'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function video_load($nid) {
  print_r($nid); 
}
```

Whenever I am trying to access http://example.com/video/nid, I get a 404 error. Please help.

Comment: Did you assign the permission?

Comment: Yeah, but 404 mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function example_video_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['video/%'] = array(
        'title' => '',
        'page callback' => 'video_load',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}

function video_load($nid) {
    print_r($nid); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the path associated to your menu item is using a wildcard ("%nid"), but your code is not defining an auto-loader for that wildcard.

- For a wildcard such as "%nid" Drupal is looking for a function called `nid_load()`, which doesn't exist; if you want to use `video_load()`, then the placeholder should be "%video" and not the one you are using. If that part of the path is a node ID, then you should use "%node" that would cause Drupal to use `node_load()`, which is a function defined from the Node object and that returns a node object for the node ID passed as argument.
- The auto-loader function should return an object or an array. If the auto-loader function is not returning a value, then Drupal would act as if the returned value is `FALSE`, which is the value that causes Drupal to return to the user the "page not found" error, as it understands the value as meaning "I didn't found what the user is looking for." Return an object (which is what [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/6) does), or an array, and the user will not see the "page not found" error anymore.

In your case, the URL for the menu item defined from the module is something similar to http://example.com/video/1, or http://example.com/video/2, where 1 and 2 are (I presume from your code, as you use "%nid" as wildcard, which should mean "node ID") the node IDs of existing nodes.
Take as example the URL for the menu item associated with the node view page, which is "node/%node"; you invoke that page with, e.g., http://example.com/node/1, and Drupal shows you the content of the node with node ID equal to 1.

If you don't want to use an auto-loader, then your menu item should use a path such as "video/%" and Drupal would not look for an auto-loader function. What I reported about the URL to use to invoke the page served from your module is still valid, except that the URL could be  http://example.com/video/asdfsdfwer, http://example.com/video/2, http://example.com/video/azder54gfg because the *%* in "video/%" matches any string.

Bart is correct in saying that using "%nid" as placeholder in the path, when the page callback, the access callback, or the title callback doesn't get any argument derived from that placeholder, doesn't make sense.

For more information, you can look at the documentation for [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6); [Wildcard Loader Arguments](http://drupal.org/node/224170), [Wildcard usage and core's wildcards](http://drupal.org/node/209056), [Dynamic argument replacement (wildcard)](http://drupal.org/node/109153), [Wildcard, ancestors and fitness](http://drupal.org/node/109134); and, as general information on how Drupal menu system work, [Drupal menu system (Drupal 6.x)](http://drupal.org/node/102338).

Answer (score 1):

The page callback should return the content of the page as a string. See [`menu_execute_active_handler`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_execute_active_handler/6) about how the page callback is invoked and [index.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/index.php/6/source) about what is done with the result of `menu_execute_active_handler`.

This doe not explain the 404, but it's the next trap you will fall into.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot page arguments!

> "page arguments": An array of arguments to pass to the page callback
>   function, with path component substitution as described above.

Comment: I have set argument to the menu array
'page arguments' => array(1),

But still drupal giving me 404.

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: And I have cleared cache, but 404